# Where can I find screenshots of failed tests with EarlGrey?

Tags: screenshot, xcode-ui-testing, earlgrey

I'd like to add screenshots to CI-reports of my EarlGrey tests.

I know I can use `GREYScreenshotUtil.takeScreenshot()` and `GREYScreenshotUtil.saveImage` to create custom screenshot and specify its name and path to save, but it helps only in particular situations, while I need to get screenshot in all kinds of fails. So, it looks like EarlGrey makes such screenshots every time when tests fail.

Where does it save them?

And can I set a specific name and path for all these screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found Decision:

```
//swift
GREYConfiguration.sharedInstance().setValue(path!, forConfigKey: kGREYConfigKeyArtifactsDirLocation)
```

Just didn't mention it in FAQ before

Comment: Do feel free to add it in the faq if needed.